# Convert emoji cheat sheet to android emojis?

Tags: android, view, textview, emoji

I get a text from a WebService like this:

```
Hi :smile:
I like your music :+1:
```

I need show this as emojis in android application and show in TextView

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this in my application to decode Trello emojis, works like a charm.

https://github.com/nimish17/androidemojimap